# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, raspberry-pi, gpio

Im trying to add gpio support to a project on my raspberry pi 3 model B but i keep encountering an error with bindings when i try to ng serve my app. This problem persists when I try to use any other gpio package.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
76:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
...
...
...
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js
@ ./src/app/ui/...
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
76:43-53 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
...
...
...
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js
@ ./node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js
@ ./src/app/ui/...
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

I'm trying to use rpi-gpio (www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio)(I installed all dependencies seperatly aswell).

Versions:

- node: v9.3.0 (using nvm)
- npm: 5.6.0
- gcc: (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 6.3.0 20170516

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pagode-shotterkas",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.2",
    "angular4-drag-drop": "^1.1.2",
    "bindings": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-eid": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "epoll": "^1.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "nan": "^2.8.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.1.0",
    "rpi-gpio": "^0.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.95",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a possible bug in the `bindings` project. There is an open GitHub ticket regarding this issue: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings/issues/42